# How do I edit a button's attribute if it is in a list (Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I have a list of 100 buttons in Tkinter, which each have their own text attribute.

```
buttonlist = [button00], [button01], [button02], [button03], etc...
```

I can edit each of the attributes using, for example,

```
button54.config(text = "example")
```

This works fine. But then, when I try to change its attribute by addressing the list, for example:

```
buttonlist[54].config(text = "example")
```

It returns the error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'config'
```

I don't understand why this happens. If anyone knows how to fix this, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a list of buttons. You have a tuple of lists, each with one button. This is how you define a list:

```
buttonlist = [button00, button01, button02, button03]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not creating a list full of buttons, you are creating a tuple full of lists of buttons.
Try removing the brackets from your buttomlist. Instead add them around the hole thing

like this:

```
buttonlist = [button00, button01, button02, button03, etc...]
```

Comment: I see, thank you! The issue lay in the fact that I have very limited knowledge of lists.